# Classifying functions that satisfy $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq M|x-y|^{\alpha}$

Tags: real-analysis

If $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a (not necessarily continuous) function satisfying

$$
|f(x)-f(y)| \leq M|x-y|^{\alpha}
$$

where $M$ and $\alpha$ are fixed real numbers and $\alpha > 1$. Classify all such functions $f$.

Comment: think derivative

Comment: That's what I was told to do but I can't seem to figure this out

Comment: No derivative is needed--as was explained to answer some previous questions on the site that this one is a duplicate of.

Answer (score 1):

for $x = a$ and $y = a + h$, then: $\left|\dfrac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h}\right| \le M\cdot |h|^{\alpha - 1}$, and letting $h \to 0$ we have: $|f'(a)| = 0$, implying $f'(a) = 0$ so $f$ must be a constant function.

Comment: @ellya: LAcarguy just show that these functions are all differentiable and has derivative 0.

Comment: How could I show that $f$ is differentiable?